# Downloading file using multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, cgi, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to put multiple files(ard 25k) into a zip file using multithreading in python cgi. I have written the script below, but somehow the response I get has content length 0 and there is no data in the response. This is my first time using multithreading in python. Is there anything I am missing in the code. Does the output gets printed even before the data is posted?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
b = StringIO()
z = zipfile.ZipFile(b, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

def read_file(link):
    fname = link.split('/')
    fname = fname[-1]
    z.write(link, fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    fileLinks = form.getvalue("fileLink")

    p = Pool(10)
    p.map(read_file, fileLinks)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    z.close()
    zipFilename = "DataFiles-" + str(time.time()) + ".zip"   
    length = b.tell()
    sys.stdout.write(
        HEADERS % ('application/zip', zipFilename, zipFilename, length)
    )
    b.seek(0)
    sys.stdout.write(b.read())
    b.close()
```

Sequential version of the same code:

```
 for fileLink in fileLinks:
     fname = fileLink.split('/')
     filename = fname[-1] 
     z.write(fileLink, filename)
z.close()
```

Comment: Does a single-thread version of your algorithm work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, let me try it and see.

Comment: I have tried with single thread and limiting the number of files to 1000. It doesn't work. It gives same response with zero content length.

Comment: Then the issue is not multithreading!

Comment: Sequential version of the same code works. Adding the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be that `ZipFile.write()` (`ZipFile` in general) is not thread safe.

You must somehow serialize thread access to the zip file. This is one way to do it (in Python 3):

```
ziplock = threading.Lock()

def read_file(link):
    fname = link.split('/')
    fname = fname[-1]
    with ziplock:
        z.write(link, fname)
```

There should be no advantage to doing it that way because what the lock is effectively doing is serializing the zip file creation.

Some parallelization may be achieved with this version, which reads the file contents before adding them to the zip file:

```
def read_file(link):
    fname = link.split('/')
    fname = fname[-1]
    # the file is read in parallel
    contents = open(link).read()
    with ziplock:
        # writes to the zip file a re serialized
        z.writestr(fname, contents)
```

Yet, if the files reside on the same file system, it is likely that the reads will, to all effects, act as if they had been serialized by the operating system.

Because it is files, the possible target for parallelization would be the CPU-bound part of the process, which is the compression, and that doesn't seem possible with the *zip* format (because a `zip` file behaves like a directory, so every `write()` must leave the state ready to produce a complete archive upon `close()`).

If you can use a different compression format, then parallelization would work without locks using *gizp* for compression and *tar* (`tarfile`) as the archive format, as each file could be read and compressed in parallel, and only the *tar* concatenation would be done serially (the `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` archive format).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Appreciate your help. I will try it out and let you know.